# How to handle state when my activity's dialog looses focus when system dialog is shown in Android

Tags: android, android-dialog

In my application I want to handle the state if my displayed dialog looses focus(e.g. if my dialog is show and any system dialog(like low battery dialog or Power button dialog) appears on top of that).

Is there any way to capture this scenario? I did not find any method for dialog having `onWindowFocusChanged` method.

My activity's `onWindowFocusChanged` does not work here.

Answer (score -1):

If you use a [DialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment.html) when the activity goes to the background (or something comes in foreground of your app) the dialog `onPause` will be called, then upon returning to your app/activity/dialog, the `onResume` will be called.

Always use `DialogFragment`, the `Activity` dialog lifecycle methods are depreciated for a reason.

Examples of how to use `DialogFragment` can be found in the docs [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html).

Comment: Thank you for reply. But is there any other way to make this work without using DialogFragment?

Comment: Possibly but why would you not want to use it? Its supported all the way back to API4.